# How to import cv2 on Jetson nano under a virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, nvidia-jetson

If you aren't using a virtualenv, the cv2 module is imported successfully

```py
nano@nano:~$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.1'
>>>
```

However, if you create a virtual environment, cv2 is not found

```py
(env) nano@nano:~$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: OpenCV needs to be installed under virtualenv. See [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/).

Comment: Normally that would be correct, but this is not the right advice for the Jetson platform.  Nvidia packages a custom-built version of OpenCV that takes advantage of GPU acceleration.  Installing OpenCV this way will work, but you'll not be able to take full advantage of the hardware.

Answer (score 6):

More specifically it seems you need to simlink opencv as:

first: cd into your_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

and:

```sh
ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so cv2.cpython-36-m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: For me this is the path: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` . You can do an individual search with this command: `find /usr/local -name "*opencv*" -o -name "*cv2*"`

Comment: One more convenient thing: you can enter the activated virtualenv's site-package dictionary with this command: `cdsitepackages`

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/` to your virtual env folder, for example `env/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can install opencv in virtual environment or can make symbolic link of library to vitual env in bashrc.

```
ln -s source_file destination_file
```